# Powershell Array values contain no values from wildcard array

Tags: string, powershell, where-object

I have the following code

```
@Wildcard_Array = @ ( '"' , '[' , ']' , '*' )
$SAMAccounts = Import-Excel -Path $PSScriptRoot\PulledData.xlsx | Where-Object -Property SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME -notcontains @Wildcard_Array
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that no values are returned that contain wildcard values.

If I use this I can filter dates which I want to I just don't know how to filter out and values with wildcards/invalid options.

```
$SAMAccounts = Import-Excel -Path $PSScriptRoot\PulledData.xlsx | Where-Object -Property DT -eq (Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0 -Format G | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME
```

Example:

```
SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME     DT
!@$#*                1/11/2024
User1                1/11/2024
```

I've tried contains, notcontains, cnotconains, notlike, and inotlike but honestly I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`.IndexOfAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexofany?view=net-8.0) in this case:

```bash
$Wildcard_Array = [char[]] ('"', '[', ']' , '*')

@'
SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME,DT
!@$#*,1/11/2024
User1,1/11/2024
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv |
    Where-Object { $_.SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME.IndexOfAny($Wildcard_Array) -eq -1 }
```

Another option could be to convert your array into a regex pattern and use [`-notmatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#matching-operators):

```bash
$Wildcard_Array = '"', '[', ']' , '*' | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }
$filter = '(?:{0})' -f ($Wildcard_Array -join '|')

@'
SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME,DT
!@$#*,1/11/2024
User1,1/11/2024
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv |
    Where-Object SAM_ACCOUNT_NAME -NotMatch $filter
```

`-contains` looks for an exact match in a collection, so it isn't an option:

```bash
'foo', 'bar' -contains 'bar' # True
'foo', 'bar' -contains 'b'   # False
```

And `-like` would require to first escape the wildcard characters (can use `[WildcardPattern]::Escape` similar to `[regex]::Escape`) and then use additional wildcards. I wouldn't recommend this method in this case.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to modify what you had to make it work for me.

Comment: @RobertStolle glad it was helpful :)